Azure DevOps notifications - email is being sent when it sits too long in one state
I would like to set up a notification that an email is being sent, if an item sits too long (more than 2 days) in one particular state. How can I do that in Notification feature?
I tried to set it up, but not sure what formula to use to indicate that number of days.

I don't think that's supported out-of-the-box. You might need to create a custom automation to do that.


I would like to set up a notification that an email is being sent, if an item sits too long (more than 2 days) in one particular state. How can I do that in Notification feature?

I'm afraid there's no out-of-box way to achieve this currently. The Notification only monitors on the work item change only.

The mostly nearby way is to check if there are any changes(not only state change) on these work items, send email notification of these work items in DevOps pipeline.
Details below:

we can try to list the work item from query like below for a check.
To list user story with New state, and have no changes in 2 days on my side:


We can use rest api Wiql - Query By Wiql to achieve the same.


Hence, in devops pipeline, we can run the pipeline every 2 days with schedule trigger, send out these work items in email:


Yaml sample below:
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "0 0 */2 * *"
  displayName: Run every two days
  branches:
    include:
    - main

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Define your organization, project, and personal access token
      $organization = "orgname"
      $project = "projectname"
      $pat = "$(pat)"
  
      # Define the date 2 days ago
      $date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
  
  
      # Define the API endpoint
      $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0"

  
      # Define the query
      $query = @{
          query = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '$project' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.ChangedDate] < '$date' AND [System.State] = 'New'"
      } | ConvertTo-Json
  
      # Convert the PAT to a Base64 string
      $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
  
      # Make the API request
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $query -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization="Basic $base64AuthInfo"}

      # Output the response
      $response.workItems.id

      # Get the work item IDs
      $workItemIDs = $response.workItems.id

      # Convert the work item IDs to a string
      $workItemIDString = $workItemIDs -join ", "

      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WITlist;]$workItemIDString"

- task: SendEmail@1
  inputs:
    To: 'zwxxxx5@hxxil.com'
    From: 'zwxxx@hoxxxxl.com'
    Subject: 'The work item not changed in 2 days'
    Body: |
      This is the work items not changed in 2 days for "New" state "User stories": 
      $(WITlist)
    BodyAsHtml: false
    AddAttachment: false
    SmtpServer: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
    SmtpUsername: 'zwxxxx4@hotmail.com'
    SmtpPassword: '$(pwd)'

I can receive the work item list:



Thank you!! I'm not a technical person so I will ask my team to help with the last part but thank you for the ready-to-use solution!!

You are welcome! You can change schedule cron as 0 0 */1 * * in pipeline yaml which will check every day. :)
